# MVC 4 Ajax call is not made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to fix a problem in my app for a couple of days now and I can't figure out what's happening.

I'm developing a MVC 4 application. I have a view in which there's a div that I load with more html with an ajax call that is executed on the `$(function() { ... });`. That ajax call works fine.

Problems start when I make the second ajax call. I paste the code below :-

In the main view :-

```
<div class="body" id="loadedData">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(function(){
      loadData("@Url.Action("Authorizations","User", new { id = Model.ID })");
   });

   function loadData(url){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loadedData").html(data);
        }
    });
   }
</script>
```

And the partial view that is loaded in the div it's this:

```
@if (ViewBag.UserAuths != null){
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Operations
          </th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
      @foreach (var prod in ViewBag.UserAuths){
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @prod[0]
              </td>
              <td>
                 <a href="" onclick="loadData(@Url.Action("RevokeAccess", "User", new {    id = ViewBag.UserID, op = Int32.Parse(prod[1])}));">Remove</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      }
  </table>
 }
```

The problem happens when I click on the link in the HTML that's loaded by ajax (Remove). When i click, the page 'blinks' but nothing happens. I've put a breakpoint in the  RevokeAccess function in UserController and it never stops.

Please help!

Edit:

There's other thing, when i click on the link, in the Chrome console it's shown a  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" message, but it disappears very quickly, i don't know why.

Comment: Add event.preventDefault() to the load function

Comment: specify the type of data your passing in your ajax call, like `dataType: "json"`

Comment: when you are clicking anchor then it is calling loaddata or not??

Comment: give datatype and content type in ajax call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery don't use *inline events*. Bind click event using jQuery. As you are fetching Partial View you can use `.load()` which is much simpler.

*Script*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $("#loadedData").load("@Url.Action("Authorizations","User", new { id = Model.ID })");      

       $("#loadedData").on('click', '.anchor', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();//Stop default action  
            $("#loadedData").load(
                $(this).data('url'),  //Url
                { id: $(this).data('id'), op : $(this).data('op')}, //Parameters
                function(){
                    //Perform any action if any
                }
            );
       })
   });

</script>
```

*Change Your Partials as*

```
@if (ViewBag.UserAuths != null){
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Operations
          </th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
      @foreach (var prod in ViewBag.UserAuths){
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @prod[0]
              </td>
              <td>
                 <a class='anchor' href="#" data-url='@Url.Action("RevokeAccess", "User")' data-id="@ViewBag.UserID" data-op="@Int32.Parse(prod[1])">Remove</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      }
  </table>
 }
```